# VSCode imports not working in Python, but working in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on a project I'm doing in Python, but for whatever reason, imports are not working properly. I initially thought the issue had something to do with my code, but when I tried opening my project in PyCharm, importing from another module worked just fine. I had no issues whatsoever. The directory of my project looks something like this:

```
C:.
└───project_folder
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───app
    │       thing.py
    │       another_thing.py
    │
    ├───data
    │       data.py
    │       graph.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───models
    │       abc.py
    │       def.py
    │       ghi.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───test
            test_abc.py
            test_def.py
            test_ghi.py
            __init__.py
```

when I go into the test directory, and put in test.abc:

```
from models.abc import ClassABC #Class in abc.py
```

instead of importing from the module from the specified package, I get a ModuleNotFoundError, and VSCode just doesn't recognize the package as an actual package and thinks 'models' is a module. I was curious, so I decided to try and see if the same issue persists if I try using PyCharm, and for whatever reason, the code is running without any issues, and everything is running perfectly fine. The issue is only is VSCode, and I don't know why. Can someone help me out?

Comment: If your current directory is `project_filder`, and you type `python test/test_abc.py`, it will work.  If your current directory is `project_folder/test`, it won't work. because it has no idea how to find `models`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried that, and it still didn't work. I'm still getting the same error I had before.

Comment: I'm not sure how the habit of putting test scripts in a `test` directory ever got started.  In order to use the modules within the project, the test scripts should be at the top level.

Comment: Your `__init__.py` in `project_folder` is strange.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn ok, but removing it doesn't help either. The issue isn't the project not working at all. The issue is the project specifically not working in vscode, but still working in another IDE like PyCharm...